# Show dynamic data with dynamic colours in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an array of data as follows

**getDates** stores all the dates set by the backend team (01 => 1 April, 02 =>2 April and so on)

**getAllApplicantsPerDay** stores the number of registrations on each day

```
Array Name                                          All Data                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------
getDates                                         '01', '02','03'

getAllApplicantsPerDay                           6,4,5,8,7,8
```

So, basically the data stored are as follows

```
getDates

Array ( [0] => '01' [1] => '02' [2] => '03')

getAllApplicantsPerDay   

Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 8 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 )
```

Now, as per the requirement of the backend team, they can change the date by adding or removing some dates

So, let's say they add 3 days, the new **getDates** array would be

```
getGender

Array ( [0] => '01' [1] => '02' [2] => '03' [3] => '04' [4] => '05' [5] => '06')
```

In accordance,  **getAllApplicantsPerDay** would also change. I would also want different colours each time (randomly selected color)

However, I cannot show that in a graph. I dont know the syntax to do it.

here is what I tried so far

Script

```
  var config111 = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [
        <?php  echo json_encode($getDates); ?>
        

      
        ],

        datasets: [{
          label: 'DAILY REGISTRATIONS',
          backgroundColor:'rgba(178,150,200,0.9)',   ------>I want this dynamic too
          borderColor: 'rgba(70,158,210,0.9)',
         data: [

          <?php echo json_encode($getAllApplicantsPerDay   ); ?>
       
          ],
          fill: false,
        },
        
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Daily Registrations'
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false,
        },
        /*hover: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: true
        },*/
        hover: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          "animationDuration": 0,
          intersect: true
        },

        "animation": {
        "duration": 1,
        "onComplete": function () {
          var chartInstance = this.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

          ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
          ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

          this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
            meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
              var data = dataset.data[index];                            
              ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
            });
          });
        }
            },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: ' Monthly Panchayat Samiti'
            }
          }],
          /*yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Value'
            }
          }]*/
           yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
      }
    };

    $(function () {
    var ctx111 = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx111, config111);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `json_encode` would mean that you are encoding the data in JSON format. This format,may not be acceptable by `chartjs`,as `chartjs` requires *strings* for **labels**, and *numbers* for **data**.

Here is what you can do (only the required section of the code)

(Please Note):- Copy and paste this in `label` tag in `chartjs`. You can do this exact same thing for `data` tag as well.

```
labels: [
        <?php
         for($i=0;$i<count($getDates);$i++){
            echo $getDates[$i];
            echo ','; 
         }
        ?>
         
        ],
```

Also, make sure to send the data as an array from the backend, if you want to use this method.

As for the random color thing, I suggest you check out [this github repository](https://github.com/mistic100/RandomColor.php). You can search for other options for random colors as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was able to do what I wanted. In addition, I found a way to generate random colour values in Hex form

Comment: But, can I apply the same concept in pie chart as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same logic.